# Need help naming this plant!

Tags: identification

[image]

I purchased this plant from a grocery clearance table. It rang up as a fern, but the leaves remind me of some kind of begonia. Any info please?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gloxinia, possibly a Sinningia. Wikipedia describes it in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloxinia_(genus)) and also mention that botanists have been busy adding and removing members of the genus.

Plant fanciers also like breeding these plants for variegated foliage and different flower colours.

The plant you bought is likely to be a hybrid and unfortunately will most likely look good for a few months and then stop flowering. Originally a plant that goes into dormancy you can try this for the best care:

- bright diffuse light
- do not let it dry out
- fertilize at low strength every few weeks with a flowering plant fertilizer
- do not let water get on the leaves or mist it.  Water the soil directly